# Rock Paper Scissors

Tags: python

I had a test for my comp sci class and one of the questions was to make a rock paper scissors game that if player 1 won it would return -1, if player 2 won it would return 1 and if it were a tie it would return 0. I made my program and ran it and it worked but according to my professor he said it didn't.

```
def rps(x,y):
    player1 = -1
    player2 = 1
    tie = 0
    'R'>'S'
    'P'>'R'
    'S'>'P'
    if x>y:
        return player1
    if x<y:
        return player2
    else:
        return tie
```

I don't see what is wrong with it? It if you do rps('R','P') then it would return -1 because x = player1 and because Rock beats Paper. Can anyone help me to see if my code is wrong?

Comment: The lines 'R'>'S', 'P'>'R', 'S'>'P' don't do anything.

Comment: Have you already been taught what dictionaries are?

Comment: You say "it worked", but obviously it didn't work. It isn't enough that a program runs without syntax errors. Use test cases and check the results.

Comment: If you run `rps('R','S')` you get `1`, because rock beats paper. Similarly `rps('R','P')` gives `-1` because paper beats rock. But if you run `rps('S','P')` you should get `1`, because scissors beats paper, but you don't - you get `-1`, which is wrong.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor you should make that an answer because you actually answered the question that was asked unlike the posted answers that give code that would work which (to his credit) the OP didn't actually ask for.

Comment: Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizzard, Spock!

Comment: I find it incredible interesting what the OP assumed and did. I love seeing early programming mistakes. I don't know why

Comment: @Adam Gent What I also find interesting is that Python does not raise an error for doing something meaningless as `'R'>'S'` on its own line.

Answer (score 3):

There are few problems in your code:

1.
The following lines don't do anything. You can't *set* character `R` to be larger than character `S`:

```
'R' > 'S'
'P' > 'R'
'S' > 'P'
```

2.
Cause of section 1, your `if x>y:` doesn't do what you think it does. It simply checks if content of `x` is before content of `y` in the alphabet. (Supposing contents of `x` and `y` are characters)

---

Your code is kinda hard to fix as it is, I would recommend you to approach this problem from a very different angle.

Here's a solution totally different from yours, but this one works. It simply uses many `if` checks to get to your result.

```
def rps(p1, p2):
    if p1 == p2:
        return 0
    elif (p1 == "R" and p2 == "S")\
    or (p1 == "S" and p2 == "P")\
    or (p1 == "P" and p2 == "R"):
        return -1
    else:
        return 1
```

I replaced `x, y` with `p1, p2` since they represent players' choises better imo, but if you have to use `x` and `y`, just change them back.

Answer (score 3):

You can do following:

```
def rps(p1,p2):
    retval= {
        'R':{'R': 0, 'S':-1, 'P': 1},
        'S':{'R': 1, 'S': 0, 'P':-1},
        'P':{'R':-1, 'S': 1, 'P': 0}
    }
    return retval[p1][p2]
```

Answer (score 3):

You asked:

> Can anyone help me see if my code is wrong?

Yes, it is wrong. Here's why.

If you run `rps('R','S')` you should get `1`, because rock beats paper. Similarly `rps('R','P')` should give `-1` because paper beats rock. Both of these work in your code.

However, if you run `rps('S','P')` you should get `1`, because scissors beats paper, but you don't - your code returns `-1`, which is wrong.

As eumiro pointed out in the comments, the three lines

```
'R'>'S'
'P'>'R'
'S'>'P'
```

which I assume you think are defining the ordering to be used, don't actually do anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
def rps(x,y):
    return [0, -1, 1]['RPS'.index(x) - 'RPS'.index(y)]
```

Or if you want an interactive program:

```
from random import randint
['Tie', 'I win', 'You win'][randint(0, 2) - 'RPS'.index(raw_input("Enter R, P, or S: "))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def rps(x,y):
    d = {'R': 1, 'S': 2, 'P': 3}
    return ((d[x] - d[y]) + 1) % 3 - 1


for p1 in 'RPS':
    for p2 in 'RPS':
        print p1, p2, rps(p1, p2)
```

prints

```
R R 0
R P 1
R S -1
P R -1
P P 0
P S 1
S R 1
S P -1
S S 0
```